# $(f \circ f)(x)$ linear function

Tags: functions

$(f \circ f)(x)=16x+25$

$f^{-1}(\frac{23}{3})$=?

which of the following can be one of the values ​​of the function?

A-) $-4$

B-) $-1$

C-) $\frac{-3}{4}$

D-) $2$

I found $f(x)$ to be $4x + 5$, but not

$(f\circ f)(x)=16x+25$ **can it take multiple values?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)= ax+ b$.  Then $f(f(x))= a(ax+ b)+ b= a^2x+ ab+ b= 16x+ 25$. So we must have $a^2= 16$ and $ab+ b= 25$.  From $a^2= 16$, **either** $a= 4$ **or** $a= -4$.  If $a= 4, ab+ b= 4b+ b= 5b= 25$ so $b= 5$.  But, if $a= -4$, $ab+ b= -4b+ b= -3b= 25$ so $b= -25/3$.

So there are two possible functions, $f(x)$.  They are $f(x)= 4x+ 5$ and $f(x)= -4x- 25/3$.  If $f(x)= 4x+ 5$, then $f^{-1}(x)= (x- 5)/4$ so that $f^{-1}(23/3)= (23/3- 15/3)/4= (8/3)/4= 2/3$.

But if $f(x)=-4x- 25/3$ then $f^{-1}(x)= (x+ 25/3)/(-4)$ and $f^{-1}(23/3)= (23/3+ 25/3)/(-4)= (48/3)/(-4)= 16/(-4)= -4$.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that $f(x)$ is not, in fact, equal to $$f(x)=-4x-\frac{25}{3}?$$

Since then, $$f\circ f(x) = -4(-4x-\frac{25}{3}) -\frac{25}{3} = 16 x +\frac{100}{3} - \frac{25}{3}=16x+\frac{75}{3}=16x+25?$$

---

Since $f(x)$ is a linear function, you know that $f(x)=kx+n$, which means $f\circ f(x)=k^2x + kn+n$, and that leads you to the equation $k^2=16$, however, this equation has *two* solutions!

Comment: What is the answer?